# Problem Embedding External JavaScript in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, charts

I am trying to embed a 3rd party chart ([Twist](http://twist.flaptor.com)) into an HTML page.  Also on the HTML page, I am using a text input to allow for a user to dynamically enter new parameters to be sent to Twist.

In javascript, I am attempting to append the text input to the end of the call to the external chart.  I cannot, however, figure out how to have the returned JavaScript render in my page.

Let me be more specific... the instructions for embedding the chart are to put a  tag into the html.  So it would be like below, where 'paramValue' is the value passed to the 3rd party.

```
<script src='http://twist.flaptor.com/embed?size=large&gram=paramValue&span=168&'></script>
```

This works fine, but it is hard-coded to search for 'paramValue'.  The script returns more javascript that gets embedded into my page and renders a chart.  I am trying to make this dynamic by replacing 'paramValue' with the text input from a user.  However, I cannot figure out how to send that value and also have the results rendered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On behalf of Stu42:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 var paramValue = GetParamValue();
 var url = "<div";
 url += '>'
 url += "<script src='http://twist.flaptor.com/embed?size=large&span=168&gram=";
 url += paramValue;
 url += "'";
 url += '>';
 url += "</script>";
 url += "</div";
 url += '>';
 document.write(url) ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that javascript, it uses `document.write()`. `document.write()` writes to the document during loading, but if invoked after the page has been loaded doesn't work well.

In short, you can't do it by just changing `paramValue` and adding a new `script` tag.

Try to see if Twist has something for dynamic content.